# How can I copy an autoconf build to another directory for further testing?

Tags: linux, build, compilation, autoconf

If I build a package with autoconf, how can I copy everything in the source/build* directory to another location for further testing etc.?

To elaborate further, I would like to do a simple backup of some of my work by building + testing everything in one directory before copying the directory, applying some transformations to the code (that don't require recompiling), and rerunning the tests. The problem I am running into is autoconf seems to want me to run `autoreconf` in the newly copied directory requiring me to rebuild things. This is what I would like to avoid, if possible.

For example, when I try to run tests with the newly copied `m4` (without even applying any transformations), I get the following:

```
m4-1.4.18/build-aux/missing: line 81: aclocal-1.15: command not found
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.15' is missing on your system.
You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
<http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
<http://www.perl.org/>
```

## EDIT:

As @Bodo pointed out, I should say that the copying method I use is `cp -r`.

---

* I build things in the source directory without a separate build directory.

Comment: How do you copy the build to the other directory? I guess by copying you modified the time stamps in a way that `make` wants to rebuild the target. You could use something like Git to create a backup of the source code. Or you could use `tar` to copy the files with their timestamps.

Comment: I just use a standard `cp -r`. Hmm ok I will look into `tar` to copy the time stamps! Thanks. I could use Git, and I may eventually, but for what I am doing right now it seemed a little heavy handed.

Comment: Please add the clarification (about `cp -r`) to the question.

Comment: @Bodo using `tar` worked and fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By copying the data with `cp -r` you create new files with the modification time set to the time of copying. Depending on the order in which the files are copied this will result in `make` (or your build tool) to re-build the target.

You can use something like

```
cd sourcedir
tar cvf ../sorcedit.tar .
cd ../targetdir
tar xvf ../sourcedir.tar
```

to copy the files while keeping their original time stamps.

Or you could use something like Git (or any other distributed version control system) to save every step of your work. Then you can run the tests directly in the source/build directory and afterwards throw away all files (except the Git repository, of course) and use Git to re-create the source files.